# Split multiple input JSONs with jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

Given a JSON line

```
{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}{"x":33}{"asd":889}
```

of 3 independent JSON objects.

And need to handle then one by one. It would be nice to have something like

```
echo "$json" | jq --first-one
```

Expected output:

```
{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}
```

I found the only command which can remove first object and output others. [`inputs`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#IO)

```
echo '{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}{"x":33}{"asd":889}' | jq -c inputs
```

output:

```
{"x":33}
{"asd":889}
```

### How to read only first object from input stream and do not touch the rest objects?

#### Workaround

While writing this Q I found a workaround, but it looks cumbersome

```
echo '{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}{"x":33}{"asd":889}' | jq -c . | head -1
```

simply get first line...

Comment: Here was another than @peak's answer. Hey author, it was not bad. Please return  it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slurping should, in general, be avoided if possible.  If your jq has `input`, you could simply write:

```
echo '{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}{"x":33}{"asd":889}' |
  jq -n input
```

If your jq does not have `input`, now would be a great time to upgrade to jq 1.6.  If that is not an option, then by all means use the -s option, e.g. `jq -s '.[0]'`

Comment: Yes that is what i need. But why? How -n in compination with input works? without -n it writes `{"x":33}` and `jq: error (at <stdin>:1): break` - 2nd object

Comment: When invoked without the -n option, jq automatically reads the first JSON entity before `input` is executed.  In the present case, we want to turn off that default behavior.