# Take only first json object from stream with jq, do not touch rest

Tags: json, shell, jq, fifo

This thread [Split multiple input JSONs with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53496484/split-multiple-input-jsons-with-jq) helped me to solve one problem. But not other.

```
mkfifo xxs
exec 3<>xxs  ## keep open file descriptor
echo '{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}{"x":33}{"asd":889}' >&3
jq -nc input <&3  ## prints 1st object '{"a":0,"b":{"c":"C"}}' and reads out the rest
cat <&3 ## prints nothing
```

My problem is to make `jq` stop reading after first object is read, and do not touch other data in stream (fifo). So `cat` should show the rest of data: `'{"x":33}{"asd":889}'`.

#### How to achive that with jq?

Comment: You probably can't. `jq` has limited input facilities, and as far as I know there is no way to limit what it actually *reads* to the bare minimum it needs for its filter.

Comment: `jq -n 'input'` would extract a single object from the incoming string, but only after reading *at least* enough data to find a complete JSON value in that data.

Comment: From `man jq`: "At this time jq has minimal support for I/O, mostly in the **form of control over when inputs are read.**"

Comment: As it does not seem to be possible, please consider making an enhancement request at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues. In the meantime, I'm wondering whether this is a real problem or an xy-problem (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). In any case, if you need a workaround, I'd suggest using jq to split your JSON into two (or more -- depending on what you're actually trying to do) separate files...

Comment: There is a producer which writes jsons to stream (pipe), on my side I need to handle them one by one, in other words filter input stream, handle, and produce output. I should update question to describe details.

Comment: @guys, Thank you for responses.

Comment: @chepner The input command eats both numbers: `printf '%s\n' 1 2 | { jq -n input; cat; }`

Comment: @ceving Yes, that's why I said "at least". `jq` is reading chunks of bytes from standard input at a time, not just a single byte. If it finds the first newline in the middle of a chunk, it can't put the rest back on to standard input for the next command to read.

Answer (score 2):

`jq` doesn't have to read to the whole input to get the first value. This can be verified by feeding an infinite sequence of values to jq which takes the first value and exit:

```
yes '{}' | jq -n input
```

Though, the question assumes a bit more. Namely that `jq` can read a single JSON value from a named pipe and stop reading *"right at that point"* so the rest can be then read by `cat`.

```
mkfifo xxs
exec 3<>xxs              ## keep open file descriptor
echo '1 2 3' >&3
jq -nc input <&3 >first  ## Get first value
cat <&3 >rest            ## Nothing to show jq read all data
```

This gets more complicated as we don't know where that first value ends and most Unix programs (jq included) read input in larger chunks to limit the number of read syscalls.

`jq` would need an option to read its input one byte at a time. And, while this could be implemented, it may be of limited utility.

The closest thing I can think of is to output the first value to
`stderr` and the rest to `stdout`.

```
jq -n 'input | stderr | inputs' <&3 2>first 1>rest
```

Input is processed in a streaming fashion (one input value at a time) and you can pipe `stdout` and/or `stderr` to something else. Though the whole input has to be valid JSON and it will be prettified while passing through `jq` (unlike with cat above).

---

If reading from a named pipe is not a requirement and you can afford to read the input from a file. Then, you can access the first value and the rest in two separate invocations.

```
echo '1 2 3' > in
jq -n 'input' in >first
jq -n 'input | inputs' in >rest
```

If stream processing is the goal, it may also be possible to do everything in a single `jq` script that processes its input incrementally.

This all assumes top-level values. Though, `jq` can also process nested structures incrementally using the `--stream` option.

Comment: You are misinterpreting the question. It's not how to output only the first input, but how to read *no more* than the first output from the input.

Comment: @chepner I see what you mean. I wouldn't rely on `jq` reading "exactly" one value from the input as it would have to call `read(2)` one byte at a time to not go pass the first object. The closest thing I can come up with is outputting the rest to stdout. Though this has to be valid JSON and will be reformatted by `jq`. I'll try to clarify.

Comment: You are assuming the input `in` is something you can re-open or reset to the beginning of the stream. That's not the case for the OP, who was using a named pipe.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to partially read a stream you will probably need to do it yourself.
You could write a trivial C program to do this.
I doubt there are any off-the-shelf parsers you can find to specify stopping the read of a stream after n objects.
As mentioned before, most stream readers will use stdio and read all they can into a buffer.